# Android - is it error-prone to use SharedPreferences for managing the user as being logged in?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using SharedPreferences to manage a sort of a "session" for the user and keeping them logged in until they explicitly press log out which is when I delete everything from the SharedPreferences.

When a user logs in, I do this:

```
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( LoginActivity.this);

            prefs.edit()
            .putString("first_name", firstName)
            .putString("last_name", lastName)
            .putString("email", email)              
            .putString("user_id", user_id)
            .commit();
```

Its been working 90% of the time, but every so often, this stuff does not get written to SharedPreferences, causing the user to never be seen as logged in by the system.

Any idea why that might happen? Is it a security issue on some phones?

A note: I put these values into the SystemPreferences when a remote server responds after actually adding the data to the database, and even though the data is added to the db, the values aren't being saved on some devices.

This is the code to get the preferences:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( ProblemioActivity.this);

String firstName = prefs.getString( "first_name", null); // First arg is name and second is if not found.
String lastName = prefs.getString( "last_name", null); // First arg is name and second is if not found.
String email = prefs.getString( "email", null); // First arg is name and second is if not found.
String user_id = prefs.getString( "user_id", null ); // First arg is name and second is if not found.
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Please supply the code where you READ the preferences. Maybe you read a different preference

Comment: @stefanbachert just saw your comment - the code for how I get the preferences is now added to my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its fine to use SharedPreferences for storing temporary data (like session). But instead of using `commit` you should use `apply`, because **commit** only saves the changes but doesn't update the already initialized preference object. And when you use **apply**, it updates the values of preference object and asynchronously saves (*commit*) the changes too.

> **commit()**
>
> Commit your preferences changes back from this Editor to the
>   SharedPreferences object it is editing. This atomically performs the
>   requested modifications, replacing whatever is currently in the
>   SharedPreferences.
>
> Note that when two editors are modifying preferences at the same time,
>   the last one to call commit wins.
>
> If you don't care about the return value and you're using this from
>   your application's main thread, consider using apply() instead.

.

> **apply()**
>
> Commit your preferences changes back from this Editor to the
>   SharedPreferences object it is editing. This atomically performs
>   the requested modifications, replacing whatever is currently in the
>   SharedPreferences.
>
> Note that when two editors are modifying preferences at the same time,
>   the last one to call apply wins.
>
> Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent
>   storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory
>   SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to
>   disk and you won't be notified of any failures. If another editor on
>   this SharedPreferences does a regular commit() while a apply() is
>   still outstanding, the commit() will block until all async commits are
>   completed as well as the commit itself.
>
> As SharedPreferences instances are singletons within a process, it's
>   safe to replace any instance of commit() with apply() if you were
>   already ignoring the return value.
>
> You don't need to worry about Android component lifecycles and their
>   interaction with apply() writing to disk. The framework makes sure
>   in-flight disk writes from apply() complete before switching states.

Comment: thanks!! So should I just go ahead and change all the commit() to apply() ?  ....the two descriptions read the same to me...or am I just not noticing a subtle difference? :)

Comment: Yes, you should switch to apply, because it will give you sudden changes and your object **prefs** will depict the latest values on change

Answer (score 1):

You are in danger to use two different SharedPreferences.

You set

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.
    getDefaultSharedPreferences( LoginActivity.this);
```

but you read

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.
    getDefaultSharedPreferences( ProblemioActivity.this);
```

I always get confused by the different Preferences. So I use meanwhile

```
activity.getSharedPreference("Key", Mode);
```

when I want to access the same preference across different activities